# search and replace with sed special character

Tags: text-processing, sed, xml

I need to perform search and replace using sed.
starting from this sample text for example :

```
<TextView
                        android:textSize="20.0sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
```

i wanna replace all occurrences of `android:textColor="@android:color/white"` with `android:textColor="#ffff5d"`

I spent over 3 hours (yes so frustrating) without success
the closer I get is

```
sed -i "s/"$android:textColor=\"@android:color/white\""\|"$android:textColor=\"#ff4000\""/g" path to file.xml
```

but it's far from right.
as results is

```
androidwhite"|:textColor="#ff4000"/white"
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you give a larger and more complete example of your XML document so that we can recommend a robust and safe way of parsing it with an XML parser?

Comment: Errors I have detected: You have a lone pipe sign there in the middle of your `sed` code, which probably shouldn't be there. You have an unquoted `$android`, which the shell probably expands to an empty string. And you didn't quote the slash in `color/white`. Suggestions: To quote the $, use single quotes, and to avoid having to quote slashes, use a different character to separate regular expression from substitution; for example `sed 's|android:textColor="@android:color/white"|android:textColor="#ffff5d"|g'`. And as @Kusalananda says, `sed` is normally not the right tool for processing XML.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` to edit XML files is almost never a good idea. If the XML file is formatted slightly different, your method will break.

If you had proper XML (and I guess you will need to have that anyways), you could use XML tools, e.g. `xmlstarlet`.

Proper `xml` means, you have at least:

- The `android` namespace declared somewhere
- The `TextView` tag gets closed (e.g. with `/>`)
- Attributes exist only once per tag (in your example, `android:textColor` is defined twice, which makes the XML invalid).

As you don't give a complete example of your XML document, I made it minimally valid like this:

```xml
<TextView               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:textSize="20.0sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
/>
```

Now you can use `xmlstarlet`:

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed -P -S \
  -N android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" \
  -u "//TextView/@android:textColor" \
  -v "#ffff5d" \
file.xml
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:textSize="20.0sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffff5d"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For my limited usage

`sed 's|android:textColor="@android:color/white"|android:textColor="#ffff5d"|g'`

works fine.
I just edit some apk on the phone, so I don't even know if `xmlstarlet` binary exists for ARM 64 android.